# Copy Google Cloud Storage buckets by preserving IAM permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

How to copy `Google Cloud Storage` buckets by preserving IAM permissions.

I tried below `gsutil` command with -p option but the IAM permissions are not preserved.

```
     gsutil cp -pr  gs://<bucketname1> gs://<bucketname2>
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation on [`-p, --[no-]preserve-acl`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/cp#:%7E:text=lists%23predefined%2Dacl-,%2D%2D%5Bno%2D%5Dpreserve%2Dacl%2C%20%2Dp,-Preserves%20ACLs%20when)

> Preserves ACLs when copying in the cloud. This option is Google Cloud Storage-only, and you need OWNER access to all copied objects. If all objects in the destination bucket should have the same ACL, you can also set a default object ACL on that bucket instead of using this flag. Preserving ACLs is the default behavior for updating existing objects.

I can't seem to find any `gsutil` command `-pr`. By default, `-p` flag is enabled however only the ***OWNER*** role can preserve ACLs when copying buckets and/or objects.

You may check the documentation below regarding Cloud Storage roles and IAM permissions for `gsutil` commands:

- [IAM roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)
- [IAM permissions for gsutil commands](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-gsutil#:%7E:text=buckets.update-,cp,-Objects)

You may also check the documentation below on copying objects and gcloud SDK library for `cp` command:

- [Copy, rename, and move objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects)
- [`gcloud storage cp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/cp)